# Remove Root Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection

Our O365 tenant is not using the current SharePoint site collection **https://companyname.sharepoint.com** - at this stage we have only a couple of O365 groups and a couple of different site collections in use.

I would like to remove the existing site collection **https://companyname.sharepoint.com** and recreate it with a different template, I would go ahead and do something like this:

```
New-SPOSite -Url https://companyname.sharepoint.com -Owner Admin -Title "Company Name" -StorageQuota 1000 -LocaleID 1033 -ResourceQuota 300 -Template "STS#3" -TimeZoneId 17 -CompatibilityLevel 15
```

Will the deletion of **https://companyname.sharepoint.com** destory anything else like the existing O365 groups and/or existing site collections? Will my O365 tenant loose any functionality and/or availability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can delete and recreate the root site collection in SharePoint Online.
You can check the articles [Delete and Recreate a SharePoint Online Root Site Collection](http://itgroove.net/seek/2015/11/19/delete-and-recreate-a-sharepoint-online-root-site-collection/) to permanently delete the root site collection from recycle bin.

[Tenant Administration Delete Root Site Collection and Re-Create Doesn’t Properly Delete From Recycle Bin.](http://bexgordon.com/2015/11/tenant-administration-delete-root-site-collection-and-re-create-doesnt-properly-delete-from-recycle-bin/)

Note that you may need to wait 1-2 hours before you can actually create a new root site collection.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  So if I go ahead and remove **https://company.sharepoint.com** - it will not destroy any existing O365 groups? By that I mean, all the existing O365 groups created under /Teams/   - for example:   **https://company.sharepoint.com/Teams/HR**   or **https://company.sharepoint.com/Teams/NYCDevs** ? Where do they live?

Comment: All of your other site collections under the tenancy will stop working when you delete the root site collection, however, after you create the new root site collection and then they will begin working again.